# Strikeout all repeated words using jquery, javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there an easy way to strikeout all repeated words (excluding the first one) in a string using jquery/javascript or PHP?

Ex (using Javascript):

```
var text = 'You know that. I know that. They might know';

strikeoutRepeatedFunction(text);
```

Result: You know that. I  <del>know</del>   <del>that</del> . They might  <del>know</del> .

Thanks

Comment: you seem to have used SO before. I must insist that, please do share the code which you have tried to solve the problem. It helps us to pin point the error/mistake that you are making. It saves time, rather then coming out and asking for an all out solution from scratch, which I feel wouldn be entertained by the SO users.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary sorry about that. This time I just don't know how to start.

Comment: Cool.. No issues as such.. do try to solve them first :) Would help you and others too.. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

1. Split the string using **[`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**, it will split it by space.
2. Now iterate over them using `map()` and store unique words in an array
3. In case of repetition return string wrapped by **[`del`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del)** tag else return the string itself.
4. To avoid problem with case convert the string to lowercase while comparing , use **[`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)** for that.
5. Combine the array using **[`join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
var text = 'You know that. I know that. They might know';

function strikeoutRepeatedFunction(t) {
  var words = [];
  return t.split(' ').map(function(v) {
    if (words.indexOf(v.toLowerCase()) === -1)
      words.push(v.toLowerCase());
    else
      return '<del>' + v + '</del>';
    return v;

  }).join(' ');
}

document.write(strikeoutRepeatedFunction(text));
```

Sometimes `.` in the string may cause problem to avoid that use

```js
var text = 'You know that.  I know that. They might know. that you';


function strikeoutRepeatedFunction(t) {
  var words = [];
  return t.split(' ').map(function(v) {
    if (words.indexOf(v.replace(/^\.+|\.+$/,'').toLowerCase()) === -1)
      words.push(v.replace(/^\.+|\.+$/,'').toLowerCase());
    else
      return '<del>' + v + '</del>';
    return v;

  }).join(' ');
}

document.write(strikeoutRepeatedFunction(text));
```

Comment: 1 thing, `<strike>` is deprecated afaik,use `<del>`

Comment: @robot11 : glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Somthing less elegant :P

```
var text = 'You know that. I know that. They might know';
var x=text.split(" ");
for(var v=0;v<x.length;v++)
{
    var t=x[v];
    for(var b=v+1;b<x.length;b++)
    {
      if(x[b]==t)
      {
        x[b]="<del>"+x[b]+"</del>";
      }
     }
}

$(".div").html(x.join());
```

Check fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qj7z2ur7/14/)

Comment: @robot11 hey, it was Varun who answered :) I just edited it.  Varun,would be the right guy to answer your concerns :)

Comment: @Varun thanks for your answer but I don't need the commas.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary sorry about that :)

Comment: No issues again.. Chill :)